# sum of 'float64' column type in pandas return float instead of numpy.float64

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe in pandas. I am taking sum of a column of a dataframe as:

```
x = data['col1'].sum(axis=0)
print(type(x))
```

I have checked that `col1` column in `data` dataframe is of type `float64`. But the type of `x` is `<class 'float'>`. I was expecting the type of `x` to be `numpy.float64`.

What is it that I am missing here?

pandas version - '0.18.0', numpy version - '1.10.4', python version - 3.5.2

Comment: Can't reproduce this, you'll need to post raw data and code that reproduces this, I observe that the dtype remains `np.float64` throughout

Comment: I get `numpy.float64` throughout using pandas 0.18.1 and numpy 1.11.1.

Comment: I can reproduce it: `type(pd.DataFrame({'col1':[.1,.2,.3,.4]}).col1.sum())` - Pandas 0.18.1, numpy 1.11.1, Python 3.5.1

Comment: Is your Python binary 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: I could reproduce the error with the code that @MaxU posted on a 64bit python installation

Comment: Cannot reproduce with @MaxU's code with 64 bit Python 2.7.6, numpy 1.11.1, pandas 0.17.0.

Comment: @MaxU no repro on Pandas 0.18.1, numpy 1.11.1, Python 3.4.3, 64 bit. Only difference seems to be Python minor version.

Comment: OK, take a look at the native python `sum`, that might be the underlying reason. On 3.4.3 `type(sum((np.float64(3),)))` gives me `np.float64`.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be from the way that pandas is handling nans. When I set `skipna=False` in the `sum` method I get the `numpy` datatype

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

type(pd.DataFrame({'col1':[.1,.2,.3,.4]}).col1.sum(skipna=True))
#float

type(pd.DataFrame({'col1':[.1,.2,.3,.4]}).col1.sum(skipna=False))
#numpy.float64
```

The `sum` method is calling `nansum` from `pandas/core/nanops.py`, which produces the same behaviours.

```
from pandas.core.nanops import nansum

type(sum(np.arange(10.0)))
# numpy.float64

type(nansum(np.arange(10.0)))
# float
```

Why `nansum` is converting from `numpy.float64` to `float`, I couldn't tell you. I've looked at the `nansum` source code, but none of the functions it itself calls seem to be producing that change.

Comment: Can you specify your versions? [Mine are there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712435/sum-of-float64-column-type-in-pandas-return-float-instead-of-numpy-float64#comment66725001_39712435) and I get `np.float64` for both. I suspect a bug report might be in order, but I wonder where the difference is.

Comment: pandas 0.18.1; numpy 1.11.0; python 3.5.1; Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: when `skipna` is `True` pandas will try to use `bottleneck.nansum()`, when it's `False` pandas calls `numpy.sum()`. If `bottleneck` isn't installed, then both use `numpy` functions.